# How to split strings with multiple lines

Tags: java, arrays, list

Say I get this as a String

```
element1#element2#element3#element4
element1#element2#element3#element4
element1#element2#element3#element4
element1#element2#element3#element4

element1#element2#element3#element4
element1#element2#element3#element4
```

and then another time I get this a string

```
element1#element2#element3#element4

element1#element2#element3#element4
element1#element2#element3#element4
```

How would I create an array which would store each line individually, with its respected elements. ignoring the empty lines

Comment: Try a possible solution on your own, we can start from there

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading in each of these lines from a file? If so, just read in each line first, check if its length is > 0 and if it is split the string, otherwise read in the next line.

I see you are not reading it from a file, in that case you will need to split your string by removing any spaces as some of the other answers have mentioned and then splitting your String by '#'.

Here is my working example:

```
String s = "welcome#home\n\nDog#Cat#Eat";

    String[] first= s.split("\\s+");

    for (String first1 : first) {
        String[] result = first1.split("#");
        for(String result1: result){
            System.out.println(result1);
        }
    }
```

Of course this is for the general idea, you can manipulate it to work for your use case.

Comment: I have updated my answer but sorry I may have misunderstood, I thought you wanted to split your string by '#' but not have the spaces. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called split() in string. You can specify the regex, and an optional argument to specify how many times you will split (starting from the left).
Here is an example:

```
array = line.split(" \\| ");
```

The array will then contain the split string.

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to store the lines in a `List<String>` rather than a `String[]` and you're reading from a file, it's worth mentioning the `java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines(Path, Charset)`. the following code will read all the nonempty lines into a `List`.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collections;

//The rest of your implementation

Path pathToInput = Paths.get("path to input file");
//read the lines into a List<String> using a specified Charset, here, UTF-8
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(pathToInput, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
```